# Link to deleted question visible in user profile page, even for anonymous visitors

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, reputation-history

I stumbled over what appears to be some sort of edge case.

On http://movies.stackexchange.com I had a question deleted after about 8 months and after having a bounty on it. This probably caused some side effects, as now the question appears in the [reputation tab](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/106/shadow-wizard?tab=reputation), expand *Dec 5 '11* to see it. Here's a screenshot as anonymous visitor:

> [image]

This obviously should not happen.

Worth to mention that when viewing my own profile and ticking "show removed posts" I see the question title as text only, not as a link, on the "removed" event which is expected behavior.